# syslogd outputs '\r' as the literal characters "^M"

Tags: c, linux, embedded, syslog, busybox

So I'm running a Linux based embedded system and using Busybox syslogd for system logging. When I have a system log statement:

```
syslog("testing \r\n");
```

the log will output

**testing ^M**

but the ^M is the actual literal characters ^(5E) and M(4D)

- Is there any way to fix this without removing '\r'?

I tried removing '\r' which works but I can't do that for every log statement. I believe it has something to do with the way Busybox syslogd interprets '\r'.

Comment: Don't you mean `\r\n`?

Comment: This is just how syslogd works, it translates control characters to printable sequences. I don't think there's anything you can do in your client code.

Comment: Why do your log statements have a space and a carriage return before the newline?  Is the newline necessary, even?  It feels like you're saying "I have a pervasive bug (or misfeature) in my code; can I get syslogd to fix that for me?"

Comment: Note that the examples in the POSIX specification for [`syslog()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/syslog.html) do not include a newline at the end of the message.  The `syslog` system has to add a newline to ensure that messages from different processes are not combined on a single line in the syslog (syslogd) log files.

Comment: Note also that at least with regard to text I/O, the C standard library is responsible for translating between a single newline character as the internal representation of a line terminator, and whatever is the appropriate external representation.  `syslog()` is not exactly text I/O, but I raise this because in general, putting `\r\n` in your C strings is more likely wrong than right.  If a line terminator is needed, then `\n` alone is usually the right one, regardless of host OS.

Comment: _Why_ can't you remove all of these?